# How to SUM() a column getting from a query

Tags: sql, database

Here is my query:

```
select sum(distinct totalSell) as total 
from viewTransaction a 
where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06' 
group by invoiceNumber;
```

executing this query a column will be return. I just wanted to sum that column which i found from that query.

The column look like

```
c1 total
--------
r1 1050
r2 1050
r3 510
r4 250
r5 140
r6 2053
```

Now, i want to sum this column and get this sum value. Please help anyone....

Comment: `sum(distinct)` is (almost) never correct.

Comment: Ok, then let me know, what should i do. but i need sum of that column..

Comment: Either remove `distinct` or add an item to the group by or where clause to narrow each sum to the correct rows.

Comment: if i dnt use distinct, some duplicate data comes up.. i dnt want those Duplicate data. thats why i m using distinct. and also i need group by invoiceNumber.. I m in big trouble i think..:(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this query compiles...
"select invoiceNumber, sum(distinct totalSell) as otal from viewTransaction a where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06' group by invoiceNumber;"

You should be getting 2 columns:
invoiceNumber otal

if you wanted the sum of the column (titled as "otal") you could do...
"select sum(distinct totalSell) as otal from viewTransaction a where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06';"

^Would give you the sum of all the invoice numbers in the original query.

So instead of

invoiceNumber otal

id1            $5

id2            $6

id3            $2

id4            $1

You would get

$14

(^Clearly my own bogus sample data)

To refine due to comment...

use

sum(totalSell) as otal from viewTransaction a where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06' group by invoiceNumber;

instead of

sum(distinct totalSell) as otal from viewTransaction a where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06' group by invoiceNumber;

Comment: Sorry, i gave u wrong query..
select sum(distinct totalSell) as otal from viewTransaction a where saleDate between '2015-10-28' and '2015-11-06' group by invoiceNumber;"
I need this sum column data. In the table there some duplicate data available, and also there some data need to be grouped by invoiceNumber. So i need that column data with sum..
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: But i also added sum of duplicate value, i think my query is ok.. just i need the sum of the column, which u found after executing my given query ..u will find 1 column and 6 rows. No how to sum this column and 6 rows. That will be mu solution...